# Are Fabric events logged in test flight builds

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I have not seen any fabric events come through for builds of my app distributed via TestFlight. When downloaded through the app store (for the same build), those events do come through.

Is this because fabric detects whether the app was downloaded from the app store on device (and sends or not accordingly), or is it filtered server side.

I ask the question because I would like to understand what impact some new event tracking code will have on my app before I release it.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter that you are downloading app from store or test flight. Fabric events should work. there must be something else wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't use any logic to prevent data from being collected depending on the distribution method. I've seen this situation happen, most often, if a developer adds conditional logic to only enable Fabric in certain build types. For testing new events, trying things out locally is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks! I must admit, it's entirely possible that the volume of events from the app store version was enough to drown out any events from the test flight version. Would be great if we could filter events by version number the same way we can filter crashes, then I'd know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the version filter and what you described is more commonly seen where production data is much larger then debug or beta data.